# Proof of Cauchy Integral Formula using homotopy of curves

Tags: complex-analysis

This is from Stein and Shakarchi.

> Give another proof of the Cauchy integral formula
>
> $f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$
>
> using homotopy of curves.
>
> (Hint: Deform the circle $C$ to a small circle centered at $z$, and
> note that the quotient $\frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z}$ is bounded)

I found other posts about this problem but I couldn't find the answer to my question.
I found that the problem reduces to the problem of showing that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_r} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}d\zeta$ approaches to zero as $r$ goes to zero. I think this is where I need to use the theorem of homotopy in the book (integrals over holomorphic function on two path-homotopic curves is same). But since end points of different circles are not exactly the same, they are not path-homotopic. How can I modify the theorem to apply it in the problem?

Comment: Maybe page 46 of this compendium can be of help: https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/olver/teaching/MATH3964/cauchy.pdf

Comment: Thank you but I am specifically looking for the proof using homotopy of curves

Comment: Also observe that closed contours do not have to have the same starting points in order to be homotopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The integrals along $a$ and $b$ cancel as they are the same line in opposite directions.  Thus the integral around $C_r$ is the same as the integral along the path $aC_rb$, which is homotopic to the path $C_1$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $C$ be circle centered at $z_0$ and let $C_r$ be a circle centered at $z_0$ contained within $C$. We consider

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z_0}d\zeta = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C} \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z_0)}{\zeta-z_0}d\zeta + \frac{f(z_0)}{2\pi i} \int_{C} \frac{1}{\zeta-z_0}d\zeta$$

Now, observe that $C$ can be continously deformed into $C_r$. Thus, we have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z_0}d\zeta=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_r} \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z_0)}{\zeta-z_0}d\zeta + \frac{f(z_0)}{2\pi i} \int_{C_r} \frac{1}{\zeta-z_0}d\zeta$$

Now, we prove that the first integral approaches zero as $r \rightarrow 0$:

$$\bigg| \int_{C_r} \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z_0)}{\zeta-z_0}d\zeta \bigg| \leq \int_{C_r} \bigg|\frac{f(\zeta)-f(z_0)}{\zeta-z_0} \bigg| d \zeta \leq M \ell(C_r)=2\pi Mr \rightarrow 0$$

when $r \rightarrow 0$. The last integral is equal to $f(z_0)$, which proves the theorem.

Comment: Just to make sure, $C$ being continuously deformed into $C_r$ is the part where we want to use homotopy theorem, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, to be homotopic and to be continous deformations of each other is two ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I did is the following:
Because of continuity, $\dfrac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}$ is bounded, then $w-z$ is a removable singularity, so $\dfrac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}$ has primitive and $$\int_C \dfrac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}dw=0,$$
the result follows by calculating $\int\frac{dw}{w-z}$.